# increment pasted number keyboard

Tags: keyboard, copy-paste

Probably this question is absurd for you and i don't know if there is solution.
What i would like to do is increment the number that i have copied with control-c after each control-v that i do..

For example if i copy with control-c the number 10 from a site, then when i paste with control-v in another program the number pasted should be 11 etc..

Is there a way to do this???

Because i have to insert about 2000 number in a program and in this specific case is not possible to do script in order to automate the work..
I hope in some answer

Thanks

Comment: This is probably a better question for unix.stackexchange.com or superuser.com.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a **great** way to do it.

What comes immediate to mind is you can open Excel and have two cells, let's call them incoming and outgoing. You paste into incoming, and outgoing is setup to be incoming + 1, which you can copy and paste into your program. So you double the number of copies and pastes you have to make but it won't be the end of the world. It sure beats manually typing.

Comment: yes, i already think about excel but is quite the same thing of paste and edit by keyboard every time

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, using a small (custom written) program that would run in the background.  It would have to look at the contents of the clipboard, test if it's numeric, and if so, increment the value, if it's not already been incremented.  Shouldn't be all that hard for a windows programmer worth their salt to cook up.

Comment: thanks for the answer... i need to do this in linux. How can i access the buffer of the keyboard in c-c++?

Comment: How would that program know when the number has been pasted, so that it should increment it again?

Comment: i don't know how to do..the idea is that i copy a number and then every time i click control-v to paste, then the number must increase..in this way i need to copy the number one time and then each pasted number will be increased each time

Comment: it would have to run on a timer (e.g. every second), and check the contents of the clipboard at each iteration, and use logic to determine whether or not a new value has been pasted (by comparing the current value to the previous value).

Answer (score 0):

I did this in excel when i needed it multiple views. row() function enters current row number. Copy this cell for as many times as you want one below other and then copy paste in android studio.

=CONCATENATE("dateBoxView"|ROW()|" = fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.dateBox"|ROW()|");")

[image: Increment Numbers in Code]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using something like Pulover's Macro Creator. You press a hotkey to copy a number. Everytime you press ctrl-v a the copied number gets +1 and that new number copied to clipboard for the next paste. When you want to stop doing this just stop the macro.